Kitchen Island Counter Support
I am installing a 10ft kitchen island.  The island will house the dishwasher and a sink.  I will need support bars since it will have a 15inch overhang for seating.  Does the island need a pony wall to support the sink and dishwasher area, or will the cabinets and support bars be enough to support the quartz countertop.  Also, how about the areas where the sink and dishwasher are, how do those areas get support without obstructing the sink and such?

The quartz countertop maker should be able to tell you the exact supports needed.  Supports for openings usually go around or each side as needed.

This is a very difficult question to answer.    There are many many types of support brackets for islands.   There are some that sit in the front corner of a cabinet.    Usually you start with a drawing of what you want and see if there are options with reconfiguring or adding a wall.    I have done really large islands but we always have two rows of cabinets.     If you had your drawings included and the specs from the countertop company we could give an answer - some of these supports though are not cheap.

It'd really help if you had a sketch of what you intend.  Typically, at sinks, the sink cabinet provides sufficient support, since the cabinet has at least a crossbar across the back—if not a full back panel—and has a frame in front, like any other base cabinet.  For a dishwasher, the 2' span isn't usually a problem; if you're worried you can put a crossbar at the back of the cavity.
